# Execute a javascript till node server runs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJS. I am checking the response status of `https://encrypted.google.com/` . I have a file in my project. Let's call it ,

`status.js` :-

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); 
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Now, I also have server.js file and node is running through it.

```
node server.js
```

I want to execute the `status.js` till the nodeserver runs. That means, it should continously check the status of `https://encrypted.google.com/`. What is the recommended way to do this ?

`server.js` :-

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create express app
const app = express();

// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `setInterval` and execute the code from status.js. When your status is resolved as you want it, clear the interval via `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think the adding an event emitter was a bit unnecessary. You can try this out. This is the typescript file. For javascript replace the imports with the respective require statements.

server.ts

```
import express from "express";
import http from 'http';
import { getHttpsRequests } from "./status";

//Create an http server with  the express app
const app = express();
const server = new http.Server(app);
let interval;

// listen for requests
server.listen(4300);
server.on('listening', () => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        getHttpsRequests();
    }, 1000);
});

//register a close event on server
server.on('close', () => {
    console.log('closing server');
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

status.ts

```
var https = require('https');

export function getHttpsRequests() {
    //your code goes here
    https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function (res) {
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

       res.on('data', function (d) {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```